# Open twitter app deep link from Windows Phone 8 App (Cordova)

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter, cordova, windows-phone-8

i am developing a Windows Phone 8 app (using Cordova) and trying to access twitter through the app to post a message.

E.g. when a user clicks a button on my app, i want them to be able to go to the twitter post page with a pre-defined message.

Here's how i am doing it through my Win8 Phone Cordova app:

```
<a href="twitter://post?message=hello%20world">Post on twitter</a>
```

Actual / whats happening now:
 1. Clicking on the link in my app opens up twitter app - but on the default open page (recent tweets).

Question:

- How do i get it to open twitter app && go to the post tweet page with the default message prepopulated?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="twitter:post?tweet=hello%20world">Post on twitter</a>`

Comment: yes tried that - same result.. it just opens up the twitter app, and stays on the first/default twitter app screen. Any other ideas on what could be wrong/up here? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Xyroid - any other ideas on how i can get this to work? Would really appreciate it if you can help find a working solution here.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="twitter://compose?text=Hello%20world">Post on twitter</a>
```

Works for me.